# do I need just one didChangeAppLifecycleState in Main for app with multi routes

Tags: flutter, routes, state, lifecycle

Can I safely use just one didChangeAppLifecycleState, set up in Main, when I have 2, or more, routes, and all State changes seem to notify the didChange.. in Main?

My app has 2 routes with Main calling /Manage and /Manage calls /Game. I noticed that if I set up didChangeAppLifecycleState in Main and one of the routes, when I change State in that route, the didChange..() function is activated in both Main and the route. Can I safely assume this is how it is meant to work, and use only the didChangeAppLifecycleState in Main?

Does not make sense to me, but there must be a reason

Answer (score 0):

You can set OrientationBuilder code on runApp like this.

```
runApp(
  OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    return Phoenix(
      child: ProviderScope(
        observers: [RiverpodLogger()],
        child: MyApp(environment, orientation),
      ),
    );
  }
),
```

);

Comment: sorry Chirag, I don't understand. My problem is to ensure I handle all state changes, especially when my app is detached, (I think meaning the OS has closed the App), and when the User taps the icon, the app restarts where it was before. Does OrientationBuilder do this?

Comment: runApp is the main route of the application, without this calling, you can't get any event.  You need it before runApp is called right?

Comment: I do have runApp(MyApp()) in main(). MyApp is StatelessWidget, that sets up the 2 routes, and has home: MyHomePage().  MyHomePage() is a StatefulWidget that has ..with WidgetsBindingObserver and has the function didChangeAppLifecycleState(). I suppose my problem is understanding that this didChange.. function will get all state changes throughout the app

Comment: Can you share your code, so I can check it?

Comment: I could if you really want to see it. It is working, I suppose my problem is understanding why it works for all the didChang...() functions. In fact after this question I was going to ask another question about RestorationManager and how it handles restoring to the State. From what I have found, to restore a large amount of game data, it is best to use didChan..() to save game data on 'closing' to SharedPreferences and Disk file, and reset when Main checks sharedPrefs, rather than using RestorationManager, which works with 1 or 2 vars to restore, and I cannot get to work with multi-routes.